# Correctly Stoping AVAudioPlayer. Currently runs in Background

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, overlap

I've been strugling with this problem for quite a while.

I'm trying to make a player that contains a playlist and plays only the music files stored inside the application.

Now, i'm using AVAudioPlayer to play the mp3 files. My problem is that when i load the playlist i can't stop the previous mp3 from playing and therefor i get a mixture of sounds between the first audio and all the other audio files that i load from the playlist.

so, here is my code:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#pragma mark Audio session callbacks_______________________

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize artworkItem;            
@synthesize userMediaItemCollection;    
@synthesize playBarButton;          
@synthesize pauseBarButton;         
@synthesize musicPlayer;            
@synthesize navigationBar;          
@synthesize noArtworkImage;             
@synthesize backgroundColorTimer;       

@synthesize nowPlayingLabel, AudFile;           
@synthesize appSoundButton;             
@synthesize addOrShowMusicButton;       

@synthesize appSoundPlayer;             
@synthesize soundFileURL;               
@synthesize interruptedOnPlayback;      

@synthesize playedMusicOnce;            

@synthesize playing;                    

#pragma mark Music control________________________________


- (IBAction) playOrPauseMusic: (id)sender {


}


- (IBAction) AddMusicOrShowMusic: (id) sender {    




        [audioPlayer stop];





    // Load the Playlist direcly 


    MusicTableViewController *controller = [[MusicTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MusicTableView" bundle: nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    [controller release];




   }



#pragma mark Application playback control_________________

- (IBAction) playAppSound: (id) sender {

 //   [appSoundPlayer play];
//  playing = YES;
//  [appSoundButton setEnabled: NO];
}

// delegate method for the audio route change alert view; follows the protocol specified
//  in the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.
- (void) alertView: routeChangeAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex: buttonIndex {

    if ((NSInteger) buttonIndex == 1) {
        [appSoundPlayer play];
    } else {
        [appSoundPlayer setCurrentTime: 0];
        [appSoundButton setEnabled: YES];
    }

    [routeChangeAlertView release];         
}



#pragma mark AV Foundation delegate methods____________

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) appSoundPlayer successfully: (BOOL) flag {


}

- (void) audioPlayerBeginInterruption: player {


}

- (void) audioPlayerEndInterruption: player {


}



#pragma mark Table view delegate methods________________

// Invoked when the user taps the Done button in the table view.
- (void) musicTableViewControllerDidFinish: (MusicTableViewController *) controller {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}



#pragma mark Application setup____________________________

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#warning *** Simulator mode: iPod library access works only when running on a device.
#endif

//play audio 2 


- (void)playAudio2:(NSString*) name type:(NSString*)type 
{
    [self stopAudio];

    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer release];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]

                                         pathForResource:name

                                         ofType:type]];



    NSError *error;

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]

                   initWithContentsOfURL:url

                   error:&error];

    if (error)

    {

        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", 

              [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {

        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    }  



    [audioPlayer play];

}


-(void)playAudio
{


    [appSoundPlayer play];



}
- (void)stopAudio
{

        [appSoundPlayer stop];


}



// Configure the application.
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setPlayedMusicOnce: NO];

    [self setNoArtworkImage:    [UIImage imageNamed: @"no_artwork.png"]];       

    [self setPlayBarButton:     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay
                                                                                 target: self
                                                                                 action: @selector (playOrPauseMusic:)]];

    [self setPauseBarButton:    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemPause
                                                                                 target: self
                                                                                 action: @selector (playOrPauseMusic:)]];

    [addOrShowMusicButton   setTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Add Music", @"Title for 'Add Music' button, before user has chosen some music")
                            forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [appSoundButton         setTitle: NSLocalizedString (@"Play App Sound", @"Title for 'Play App Sound' button")
                            forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [nowPlayingLabel setText: NSLocalizedString (@"Instructions", @"Brief instructions to user, shown at launch")];



    // Configure a timer to change the background color. The changing color represents an 
    //      application that is doing something else while iPod music is playing.
    [self setBackgroundColorTimer: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.5
                                                                    target: self
                                                                  selector: @selector (updateBackgroundColor)
                                                                  userInfo: nil
                                                                   repeats: YES]];

    [self setupAudioSession];


}

// Invoked by the backgroundColorTimer.
- (void) updateBackgroundColor {

    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];

    CGFloat redLevel    = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat greenLevel  = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat blueLevel   = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redLevel
                                                green: greenLevel
                                                 blue: blueLevel
                                                alpha: 1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

#pragma mark Application state management_____________

- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void) viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


-(void) setupAudioSession
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
    if (setCategoryError){/* Handle Error COndition*/}
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
    if (activationError){
        /*handle error*/
    }
}


// just for test , delete after

-(void) myInstanceMethod: (id)sender{

    [self setupAudioSession];
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer release];
    AudFile = sender;
    NSLog(@"My Instance metthod called ok with item : %@", sender);
   [self playAudio2:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",AudFile] type:@"mp3"];

//[self setupApplicationAudio: sender];   




    NSLog(@"New Audfile is: %@", AudFile);
//    [self setupApplicationAudio];

}
+(void) myClassMethod{

    NSLog(@"Class Called ok");

}



- (void)dealloc {

/*
    // This sample doesn't use libray change notifications; this code is here to show how
    //      it's done if you need it.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] endGeneratingLibraryChangeNotifications];

*/
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self
                                                    name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                  object: musicPlayer];

    [musicPlayer endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
    [musicPlayer                release];

    [artworkItem                release]; 
    [backgroundColorTimer       invalidate];
    [backgroundColorTimer       release];
    [navigationBar              release];
    [noArtworkImage             release];
    [nowPlayingLabel            release];
    [pauseBarButton             release];
    [playBarButton              release];
    [soundFileURL               release];
    [userMediaItemCollection    release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I am sending the file name from my playlist to my player through

```
-(void) myInstanceMethod: (id)sender{

    [self setupAudioSession];
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer release];
    AudFile = sender;
    NSLog(@"My Instance metthod called ok with item : %@", sender);
   [self playAudio2:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",AudFile] type:@"mp3"];

//[self setupApplicationAudio: sender];   




    NSLog(@"New Audfile is: %@", AudFile);
//    [self setupApplicationAudio];

}
```

and i load my playlist from my mainviewcontroller using the UIModalTransition in the method

```
- (IBAction) AddMusicOrShowMusic: (id) sender {    



        [audioPlayer stop];





    // Load the Playlist direcly 


    MusicTableViewController *controller = [[MusicTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MusicTableView" bundle: nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    [controller release];




   }
```

As you can see when i load my playlist i tell the player to stop playing through

```
[audioPlayer stop];
```

but for some reason it failes to stop playing, therefore creating an overlap of sounds.

This is my problem which i'm trying to figure out.

Thank you

and best regards!

Comment: 1) #pragma mark Table view delegate methods________________   - why not just
#pragma mark Table view delegate methods
#pragma mark -.
2) Why did you prefer AVUdioPlayer to more convenient MPMusicPlayerController?

Comment: [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil]; use where u want to stop playing music

Comment: i don't know how to use the MPMusicPlayerController

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem and can't figure it out. My audioPlayer is always nil, so it makes a new instance so I get tons of files played at the same time. :-/